# Jquery highlighting multiple cells

Tags: jquery

I can highlight two cells with the same value one at a time with the below code.
I'd like to highlight multiple cells with the same value. I mean after highlighting a pair, I want to keep the previous highlights with next clicks. This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdc38yL7/). Can I get help on this, please? thanks.

Note: I'd like to be able to disable highlighting on a second click in the same cell.

```
 $(function(){
  $("table td").on("click", function(){
     $("table td").toggleClass("highlighted", false);
     var ele=$(this).html();
     $("table td:contains("+ele+")").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == ele;
     }).toggleClass("highlighted", true);     
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't toggle the class off on line 3?

Comment: can you write as an answer? please. if it works, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggleClass` work by adding or removing class so you can simply `.toggleClass("highlighted")`

```
 $(function() {
   $("table td").on("click", function() {
     var ele = $(this).text();
     $("table td:contains(" + ele + ")").filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() == ele;
     }).toggleClass("highlighted");
   });
 });
```